# How to only allow certain number of forward slashes using regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

I'm routing my application and I'd like to only allow a maximum of 2 directory subpaths following a directory path of `tags/`.  Hyphens and alnums are the only allowable characters.

The following will all validate and the bolded below will be returned to the router as a single match:

- tags/**how-to-bake**
- tags/**how-to-bake/cookies**

If there are more than 2 subpaths (or 2 or more slashes, in other words) the router should return **no** match.

My server redirects on trailing slashes (to the non-trailing slash URL) so they don't need to be taken into consideration.

I'm currently using `tags/([\w+\-\/]+)$` but this will allow infinitely many subpaths, and I am forced to check the subpath length (forward slash count) after the router returns a match.

I'm not sure how I can allow only 0 or 1 forward slashes in the character set I wrote, while having word characters possibly follow, and then have them all returned as a single match.

Is this possible with a regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Barmar's solution answers your question perfectly... This is just another version taking in account a trailing slash in the path's expression:

```
(tags\/[-\w]+\/?(?:[-\w]+)?(?<!\/)\/?)$
```

[regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/qW3aM9)

Comment: This also allows `tags/how-to-bake//`, since you made the second word optional.

Comment: I needed 'tags/' removed from the match and this worked for me: `tags/([-\w]+\/?(?:[-\w]+)?\/?)$`.  Thanks

Comment: @Barmar, indeed, corrected... Still pretty sure is a way to simplify it more... maybe xD

Answer (score 1):

This regexp should do it:

```
tags/[\w\-]+(/[\w\-]+)?$
```

It allows one word after `tags/`, followed by an optional slash and another word.

You don't need `+` inside the character class -- you said the only allowed characters are alnums and hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly what you said, match "tags/" followed by "file" or "file/file". Roughly, "tags/(file|file/file)$".

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

### `^tags(?:/[\w+\-]+){1,2}$`

Here is a tested PHP command line script which implements a commented version of the regex:

```php
<?php // test.php Rev:20130823_2100
$text = 'tags/how-to-bake/magic_brownies';

$re =   '% # Match path having two or three path segments.
        ^          # Anchor to start of string.
        tags       # Hard code first path segment.
        (?:        # Group 1 or 2 additional segments.
          /        # Path segments separated by /
          [\w+\-]+ # Path segment is one or more [A-Za-z0-9_-].
        ){1,2}     # End group of 1 or 2 additional segments.
        $          # Anchor to end of string.
        %ix';
if (preg_match($re, $text, $matches)) {
    echo("Successful match");
} else {
    echo("No match");
}
?>
```